# iphone - Upload image to flickr like Hipstamatic

Tags: iphone, flickr

I'm developing a small app allowing users to upload their photos to flickr.
I have tried ObjectiveFlickr framework, but it is too buggy (can compile on device, but not on simulator) and not very convenient for users (user must leave the app, open Safari to go to flickr website to authenticate, then switch back to the app again)

I've seen apps like Hipstamatic doing a really good job on this, it doesn't need to open Safari, everything's done in the app.

Could anyone please suggest some ways to do that?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have used ObjectiveFlickr without problems in the iOS Simulator.

Second, ObjectiveFlickr itself does not concern itself with the browser that is used for authentication. It just generates the URL you need to open to let the user authenticate your app. Whether you open this URL in Safari or in a web view inside your app is entirely your choice.